# why do I get this error "TypeError at /user/Imnew Field 'id' expected a number but got [<User: Imnew>]."?

Tags: python, django, pagination

I keep getting this error and I don't know how to fix it I changed it a few times but it's still giving me `TypeError at /user/Imnew Field 'id' expected a number but got [<User: Imnew>].`  I searched for answers online as well but to no avail what should I do?

if I need to post more code please let me know

Thanks in advance

views.py

```html
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = post 
    template_name = 'website/welcome.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 4




class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = post 
    template_name = 'user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 4

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_list_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

urls.py

```html
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user_posts'),
    path('posts/', include('posts.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('signup', signup, name='signup'),
    path('profile/',profile, name='profile'),
    path('', index, name='index'),
]
```

models.py

```html
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    date_posted=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part `user = get_list_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))` you retriving a list not user object you should use `get_object_or_404` instead to get user object directly.